# GCログに記載されている「Full GC」 と「Full GC（System）」の違い

Tags: java, gc

Full GC多発の現象調査をしているのですが
GCログにFull GCとFull GC(System)が存在しております。

前任者はFull GC(System)を外して集計しているのですが・・・
違いも判らず外すのも気持ち悪くて質問させていただきました。

ネットの海におちていなかったor2

Answer (score 1):

[Does java garbage collection log entry “Full GC (System)” mean some class called System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626680/)

に、まさにドンピシャな質問と回答があります。詳細はこの記事に譲るとして

```
System.gc();
```

を呼んだ時に記録されるもの、ということらしいです。申し訳ないですが、私自身が確かめたわけではありません。

なお Google で `"Full GC (System)"` と言った感じでダブルクォーテーション付きで検索することで、この記事に行き当たりました。

Comment: おおおありがとうございました。
友達のjava屋にも同様の回答いただきました。

実際に打ってみて確認したいと思います。